# How to handle NextJS ServerAction errors that can't reach the server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I've seen lots of solutions to handling errors that occur in NextJS ServerActions when the error occurs **in the ServerAction code itself.**

My issue is that I have an auth reverse proxy between my frontend and my NextJS server. When auth has expired, the proxy refuses to send the server action request to the server at all.

Given code like below...

```js
// From a client component

try {
    callMyServerAction()
        .catch(() => {
             // This never gets called.
        });
}
catch (error) {
    // This also never gets called.
}
```

This server action works just fine when auth is valid (this suggests that my ServerActions are properly implemented).

Since I am not directly dispatching a `fetch` and invoking an API I don't see a way to handle an error that occurs trying to reach my server.